# Business Delegate Vs Service Locator

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, ejb

What is the difference between Business Delegate and Service Locator.Do both responsible for encapsulating lookup and creation mechanism.If Business Delegate uses Service Locator for hiding lookup and creation mechanism then what is Business Delegate exclusively meant for, can't Service Locator replace Business Delegate.

Comment: Well...only you know how far you wish to take the concept of decoupling. Conceptually these two are meant to do different things...as the answer below by Gamb suggests. But yes, it is possible to lookup EJB refrences and expose business methods in the same component. For smaller applications with less business methods and less lookups to do, use one component. For larger ones, use different components

Comment: So Kaushik, is it correct if we say that both Business Delegate and Service Locator can do the same job in case of smaller applications and either one can replace the other.

Comment: Yes...that is my understanding.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you already [checked this](http://corej2eepatterns.com/Patterns2ndEd/BusinessDelegate.htm) out, but it's a good start.

> Use a Business Delegate to encapsulate access to a business service. The Business Delegate hides the implementation details of the business service, such as lookup and access mechanisms.

A Service Locator encapsulates the logic required to search and/or obtain the location, restrictions and required fields for a certain service based on a general registry. A Business Delegate encapsulates a group of related services and exposes them in a cohesive way to prevent a service customer from having to search and access all the services related to a certain functionality.

Plus, you prevent the customer from having to actually know the Service Locator and the services it should consume, leaving that to a particular Business Delegate. A client only needs that delegate to perform a group of related tasks or a task that relies in various services.

---

**Example**

A Business Delegate doesn't actually encapsulate a group of Service Locators. It provides an abstraction layer over a Service Locator to provide a cohesive subset of services. Usually there's only one instance of a Service Locator, multiple instances require an additional mapping where you should know WHICH Service Locator provides Service X, think of it as if you would need a *Service Locator Locator*.

An example should help clarify things.

Think about user account management. The `UserBusinessDelegate` looksup the registration service to register an user and then looksup the authentication service to allow a log in. The client only needs one Business Delegate to access those services and he doesn't need to know the id of both services.

Those service ids are encapsulated in the `UserBusinessDelegate` avoiding the need of declaring the ids and using a Service Locator everywhere. Think about this, what would happen if one service id changes?.

In such cases the Business Delegate in charge is updated, avoiding a direct impact for the client.

Comment: Gamb, could you please provide one scenario.As you said Service Locator encapsulates the logic required to search and/or obtain the location( i.e lookup and access mechanisms) and Business Delegate encapsulates a group of related services and exposes them, then can we say that Business Delegate encapsulates a group of Service Locators for lookup and access mechanisms for related services ?

Comment: I've updated my answer, I hope the example helps clarify things. AS others have said, a Business Delegate is useful in certain complex contexts. Small applications are good to go with a Service Locator.

Comment: Thank You Gamb, so what would be the role of Service Locator, if we create one for User Account Management .                             Business Delegate --->Service Locator -->Registration Service

Comment: The flow would be: Business Delegate exposes the function, when a client requests it the Delegate asks the Service Locator where to find it, the Service Locator provides the information, the Delegate consumes the service and, finally, returns the result of the process to the user. So basically you're correct.

Answer (score 0):

These patterns have a common point therefore this question have a lot of sense.

Both of them help a client to consume a service.

Let suppose that we have services exposed as EJB, WS or POJO.
The client may access such services using the Service Locator directly. (allowing some complexity to be encapsulated inside this component)
This improve the cliente's side code but the client is still responsible for knowing how the service is exposed. (He has to select the right Service Locator for the specific service).

One disadvantage of this solution is that the client would be highly coupled with the service.
For example: 
a) if tomorrow the service that is exposed as an EJB changes to WS we have to change the client's code (use another Service Locator).
b) If we want to test the client's code using a mock service, we have to change code.

Business Delegate come to scene to decrease the level of coupling.
Now the client interacts (in a higher abstraction level) with the Business Delegate, therefore he doesn't need to know anything else about service implementation details.

Of course the Service Locator is still useful due to the Business Delegate interacts with him.

At the simplest way, I like to think aboutn Business Delegate as an interface (improves decoupling) and a Service Locator as a helper (encapsulates infrastructure related behavior)