# Suitable architecture for EJB application with different UI implementations

Tags: jakarta-ee, design-patterns, ejb, rcp, vs-web-application-project

we have developed a stand alone application with eclipse rcp as ui layer (front end) and  ejb and jpa as back-end. Now i want to add the web application to ui layer as well.Following is the architecture we implemented.

Currently we are using Remote Method invocation to find the ejb reference(JNDI Look up).[image].What changes we should make to architecture to make it modular?Should we move BusinessDelegate and service locator to Server-side workspace.if it is so when the client can communicate?

Basically my question boils down to, what is the architecture for application which is having different UI implementations(say eclipse RCP or web or Android).

Answer (score 0):

What you have above is a classic J2EE Architecture which is a tried and tested design pattern in almost all older applications before the advent of the Spring framework.

For your UI to be a detachable component as of above the server side code starts from the Struts Action class itself if you are using it. It may/may not start with the Action class layer itself but whatever layer comes after that should be a part of the Servre side code which i mean starting from the business deligator itself.

The UI layer can be a Front controller thats it. you should be able to change it based on the different implementatons required. You can use Webservices to demarcate the UI layer from the Server layer. I guess you may have to do no changes to the above just add a Webservice layer which will do the trick. No major changes is required in the architecture above and it will work just fine

Comment: Thanks Vivek for the answer,i am not familiar with Spring framework.As you have mentioned if i move the business delegator to server side, how the communication can happen?..is there any design pattern which will help for both rcp client and web client communication?.

Answer (score 0):

> Now i want to add the web application to ui layer as well...
>   What changes we should make to architecture to make it modular?

It's not clear to me what you mean with "modular" in this context, 
but according to the diagram, you have a **well-defined service layer** (facade layer) 
which is one of the key points that you need in order to achieve your requirements. 
With this architecture, should not be a problem  expose such services layer to a new kind of client.

> Should we move BusinessDelegate and service locator to Server-side workspace?

No. These patterns "plays" in the client-side, take in mind that the aims of [BusienssDelegate and ServiceLocator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405919/business-delegate-vs-service-locator/16149818#16149818) 
is to decouple the Client from the Services. Loose coupling between Client and Service 
adds additional advantages to your architecture, however, 
these advantages are not strictly necessary in the scenario that you need implement. (add a new web front end)

> Basically my question boils down to, 
>   what is the architecture for application which is having different UI implementations(say eclipse RCP or web or Android).

With the current architecture, you should be able to invoke the services using the BD and SL from a java web component (ManagedBean) in the same way you invoke a service from the current client.
For Android clients, probably a more suitable approach could be to expose the current service through a WebService facade that acts as an intermediary between the future WS client and the current service layer.

On summary, although always is difficult to talk about architecture without to know the whole picture, i think you are in the right direction.